# Guriddo Jqgrid - Multi-select filter issue

Tags: jqgrid, free-jqgrid

I want to use multi-select filter in Guriddo jqgrid. But one of my record contains comma in the data. I want to filter those records using multi-select filter having comma in the data using delimiter as ';' and key value separator as ':'. My requirement is same as the link given in free version of jqgrid.

```
--Free jqgrid
https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ty4e68pm/2/
```

```
--Guriddo jqgrid
https://jsfiddle.net/DhirendraM/1ebymu72/37/`
```

It is working in free jqgrid properly: jqGrid 4.15.5-pre - free jqGrid using the property: inFilterSeparator: ";" but not working in my sample with version @license Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.8.5 - 2023.07-19.

Answer (score 0):

free-jqGrid and Guriddo jqGrid are not 100% compatible. In all cases you will need to check the docs if you plan to do such conversion.

Here is the [example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/searching/toolbar_multiselect/index.html) with multiselect plugin:

Here is the doc for search type [select options](https://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#searchoptions).
Actually in your case you will need to use in searchoptions the [multiseparator](https://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/about/release-notes/#additions-and-updates_1) option (not documented here) which by default is ","